# Issue with Object Variable or With Block Variable not Set Error Involving adding new sheets and range

Tags: excel, vba

Receiving Object Variable Error with ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy code line
Any reason why I'm receiving this?

```
Sub Macro3()

'Create three new sheets with unique names

Sheets.Add.Name = "SOX App-not linked to active KC"
Sheets.Add.Name = "Non SOX App-linked to Active KC"
Sheets.Add.Name = "Active KC - Delisted App"


 With Sheets("Report")
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1:N20000")
             .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Yes"
             .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("In Development", "In Production", "Projected Retire", "Retain - App and Data", "Retain - Data Only"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
             .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="Active"
             ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
             Sheets("SOX App-not linked to active KC").Select
             Range("A1").Select
            Sheets("SOX App-not linked to active KC").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Sheets("SOX App-not linked to active KC").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
         End With
        
        
        
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an object required error when I delete ActiveSheet

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `ActiveSheet` there - just

```
.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
```

(and move that line up to the sheet With block)
It's already scoped by the `With` block, and will likely error if "Report" is not the active sheet.

```vb
Sub Macro3()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Create three new sheets with unique names
    Set ws = Sheets.Add()
    ws.Name = "SOX App-not linked to active KC"
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Non SOX App-linked to Active KC"
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Active KC - Delisted App"

    With Sheets("Report")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1:N20000")
             .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Yes"
             .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("In Development", "In Production", _
                                     "Projected Retire", "Retain - App and Data", _
                                     "Retain - Data Only"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
             .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="Active"
         End With
         .AutoFilter.Range.Copy '<<< move this up!
     End With
     
     With ws.Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an object required error when I delete ActiveSheet

Comment: Sorry my bad - missed that it was in the inner With block - moved it up in my full example

Comment: I'm still getting an object required when running this. Should I specify which sheet I'm copying into?

Comment: Are all rows filtered out?

Comment: Tim Williams Yes, in the source (Report) sheet

Comment: In that case you can add a check to make sure there are rows to be copied.